# pin ImageView to bottomRight Corner in a vertical LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-sdk-2.3

I'm writing an android Application using android 2.3.3 (api v10)

I have a menu that is written using a LinearLayout with the following properties:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
```

I want to pin a small logo to the bottom right corner of the page. is that possible? and if so how ?

thank you!

kfir

Answer (score 1):

you can use RelativeLayout for this

```
<RelativeLayout ....>
<LinerLayot
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:id="@+id/layout"
>

.
.   // your elements
.
</LinerLayout>
<ImageView
src="your logo"
android:layout_below="@+id/layout"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>
</RelaytiveLayout>
```

Comment: ahh.. I think you're wrong.. it doesn't look like it's possible.